# matchbox window manager can't open display

Tags: raspbian

I am using Raspbian Jessie lite to try and create a lightweight kiosk browser with kweb and matchbox window manager, however when I try and run matchbox-window-manger it returns

```
matchbox: can't open display! check your DISPLAY variable!
```

This is a clean install and when I tried it previously it worked, can anyone help me to open matchbox?

Comment: So, what's in the DISPLAY variable? Do you have an X11 server running? How are you logged in?

Answer (score 1):

The window manager requires an Xorg server running, which creates a GUI display where windows can be managed.

First, the `-lite` image does not include this GUI server software, although if you have installed a window manager it probably has been pulled in as a prerequisite.  More on that at the end.

Create a file in the `$HOME` of the user running the kiosk called `.xinitrc` like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

matchbox-window-manger
```

I'm presuming here the last line is the actual command you've been trying; if not use whatever that is.

This file may already exist if it is user `pi`.  If so just rename it to save a backup copy and create a new one.

The file should be created by the user, or else the ownership changed to match.

I think execute permissions are required on this, so then:

```
chmod a+x .xinitrc
```

Now as that user run `startx`.  If you get "command not found" `sudo apt install xinit`.  If it still does not work leave a comment.